# PrestaShop 1.7 hook doesn't work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I writing some module for PrestaShop 1.7. But I have a problem with new hook `displayCheckoutSummaryTop`.

I register hook and then write him method.

```
public function install() {
    return parent::install()
    && $this->registerHook('paymentReturn') 
    && $this->registerHook('displayCheckoutSummaryTop');
}



public function hookdisplayCheckoutSummaryTop($params) {
   echo 'Here!';
}
```

Someone with idea where I wrong in my code, I use this functionality in 1.6 and everything works great, but in 1.7 not. I'm sorry if my question have dublicate, but my research end with unsuccess.

Thank for all helping!

Comment: Usually these hooks use a return, not an echo. But anyway, have you checked your module is in the correct hook in the positions menu?

Comment: Soryy I'm doesn't understand your question. The hook `displayCheckoutSummaryTop` call in `cart-summaary.tpl` file and must be work for the payment module. At 1.6 version I'm use `displayPaymentTop` without a problem.

Comment: In modules -> positions you can check if your module is correctly hooked. Have you confirmed?

Comment: Thank for Your help. I solved my problem with `moduleFrontController` method `redirectWithNotifications` :)

Answer (score 0):

`displayCheckoutSummaryTop` hook is called during checkout steps, when the checkout process is displayed.
You have to be sure you hooked the module to the right position (it means uninstall and re-install the module or hook it manually, with the transplant module function).

Moreover: echo won't work. You need to return a tpl template.
Then you may echo your debug inside the template itself.

Cheers.